# XML RPC -> Create User

Tags: api, xml-rpc

I am using the WordPress API via XML RPC and it does not support creating new users.

How can I go about sending a users first name, last name, email, password and photo to the XML RPC to achieve this?

I have looked at plugins such as "Extended API" but this is now outdated with WP 4.0. I have also had a read around about creating custom functions within WordPress but I've been unable to find exactly what I'm after.

Can anybody please point me in the right direction?

Kyle

Comment: I've managed to get it working. Thanks for your help @MarkKaplun

Comment: Please share the answer to help others in a similar situation, thanks.

Comment: You gotta be KIDDING me.  Why wouldn't you post the answer here!?